# image upload to picture library in sharepoint 2007 infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

i have a task in sharepoint 2007. i want to upload an image using file upload control from infopath form **or** application page and save that image to picture library. so is there any article or code available for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method using Application Page:**

Place a [file Upload control](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/) and a button in the application page and in the button click event use the below code,

```
    protected void Btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {      
    using (SPSite site = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))      
    {
              using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())    
          {   
               web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; 
                 Stream StreamImage = null;  
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)  
                {        
              StreamImage = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;   
               }         
         SPList pics = web.Lists["MySamplePictureLib"];  
                pics.RootFolder.Files.Add(FileUpload1.FileName, StreamImage);   
         pics.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false; 

                         }    
      } 
     }
```

**Method using InfoPath:**

Where the uploading of images are concerned, you can either write code to upload images to SharePoint document or picture libraries, or you can use one of two web services: 1. SharePoint Copy web service, or 2. SharePoint Imaging web service without having to write code.

Kindly have a look at the below URL:

1. [InfoPath form to upload an image to SharePoint (no code)](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2011/11/infopath-upload-images-sharepoint-2010-no-code/)
2. [Creating form in InfoPath 2010 and publishing to SharePoint 2010](http://aryannava.com/2011/05/15/creating-form-in-infopath-2010-and-publishing-to-sharepoint-2010/)
3. [Upload image to SharePoint using InfoPath](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/04052e2a-161b-4229-a4fa-2fcbd4bf6f87/upload-image-to-sharepoint-using-infopath-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)